# dropzone.js - how to control where thumbnails appear

Tags: dropzone.js

I have a nice drop down area, but if I set that to class"dropzone" then the form elements are not sent.

If I add class"dropzone" to the form, then the form elements are sent, but the thumbnails appear under the form, the submit button, etc.

How please do I tell dropzone to use my template at id "#dropzone_thumbs_here" or class ".dropzone_thumbs_here".  Do I have to fully write my own thumbnail handler? Or send form details separately?  Or is there a better method !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the answer because in the documentation it was under tips and not configuration.

In the config parameters, just added:

```
  previewsContainer: "#myPreviewContainerID",
```